# como comparar un el primer indice de los strings de un arreglo con otro arreglo en java

Tags: java, array, ordenamiento, comparaciones

tengo que comparar un arreglo ingresado por teclado con un arreglo que tiene el alfabeto para poder ordenarlo. 
quiero saber como comparar los primeros indices de cada String de mi arreglo con el alfabetico para despues ordenarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Para seleccionar el caracter de un String, y compararlo puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
public class Ejemplo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ejemplo = "abcdefg";
        String ejemplo2 = "acbshdj";
        System.out.println(ejemplo.charAt(0));
        if (ejemplo.charAt(0)==ejemplo2.charAt(0)) {
            System.out.println("Son iguales");
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que te solucione la duda

Comment: se te agradece el apoyo, pero en SO en español se pide que las preguntas tengan cierto grado de calidad mostrando, no solo la duda si no el código que han tratado y los errores obtenidos